# File server & Email server Config:

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to launch two servers with a 12 user company. I would like to know that whether it would be feasible to go with a custom built assembled serves or branded..? Cost consideration wise Branded servers are so expensive that for the same config we can built a assembled server with 25% - 35% less cost. However i need a professional advice.

Also I'm planning to go for MDaemon for email server... would it be okay..? any feed back.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Depending on who is building your server, what level of support do they provide?  If a server goes down due to a hardware failure, how quickly will they be able to get it back up and running?  What is the cost to your business if your email or file server is down for a few days?  Major vendors, although more costly, can often provide support within hours depending on the service contract.

For small businesses such as your own, it may actually be more cost effective to look at cloud based services such as Rackspace or [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/).  I myself tend to lean more toward [Rackspace Cloud Servers](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/) and [Cloud Files](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/).  They have [Private Clouds](http://www.rackspace.com/managed_hosting/private_cloud/) available too if you require additional security and may be able to customize a service to your needs.

There are of course quite a few cloud providers out there, these were just a couple of examples.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you'd have a hard time justifying 2 servers for just 12 people, regardless of price.  Even if the servers only cost $500 a server, that's still around 100 a user, even before swtitches and software, and backups.  What services do you need to provide?  I'd highly reccomend finding a cloud based solution, but not cloud servers- you will still spend too much.  A service based solution like office 365 or google apps fits better for a small office.

Without requirements for reliability and uptime it's hard to decided between home brew and brand name.  In my experince it's usually not cheaper to build it yourself unless you use subpar parts.  The advantage dell has (just to pick on one - not to reccomend) is that they are buying the same server motherboard from intel that you can buy- just cheaper per piece.

Comment: Actually management of the company doesn't like cloud solution and they want everything in house...

Comment: yuo relly need to hammer out what the security requirements are in that case, becuase you are no longer lookinga at just 2 servers if they need more security than google and microsoft provide.  As an IT professional your job isn't just to do what you are told but to present the best solution for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your company's situation. If you build a server and the power-supply fails (or motherboard dies - or both!), how fast can you replace it on your own? If you buy even a low-end Dell, HP, or IBM, the standard support will have that replaced next-business-day. That's a good chunk of what you're paying for - that, and initial build quality anyway.

My recommendation is to go with a Tier-1 server vendor, for almost all situations.

As far as MDaemon goes - without knowing what your requirements are, I'll say that I admin-ed MDaemon for a 120-person national company and I quite liked it. Configuring and troubleshooting it is quite easy, especially for a 12-user company. The webmail, antispam, IM, and add-on Outlook integrations were very nice.

Comment: But the cost diffrenece between the custom built & the branded are very high. Branded With a RAID 5/SAS, becomes US$3000 hardware alone...

Comment: That doesn't change one thing about what I said. How fast can you replace the power supply, or motherboard, on your custom-built machine?